# Mysql - Create sample data from existing rows

Tags: mysql, testing, sample-data

I have a table with about 50K rows. I need to multiply this data 10 fold to have at least 5M rows for testing the performance. Now, its taken me several long minutes to import 50K from a CSV file so I don't want to create a 5M record file and then import it into SQL.

Is there a way to duplicate the existing rows over and over again to create 5M records? I don't mind if the rows are identical, they should just have a diferrent `id` which is the Primary (Auto Increment) column.

I'm currently doing this on XAMPP with phpMyAdmin.

Comment: what your application platform? Are you using any MVC like laravel?

Comment: We haven't started working on the website yet. Infact, we are planning to test the performance of various db systems and php frameworks with this data.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11331573/mysql-copy-row-but-with-new-id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Insert into my_table (y,z) select y, z from my_table;
```

where x is your autoincrementing id.

REPEAT a (remarkably small) number of times

Comment: about 6 repetition would get you close to 100x the amount of data.

Comment: Yep, as true today as it was 2.5 years ago

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1 : Use union**

```
 insert into your_table (col1,col2)
    select col1,col2  from your_table
    union all 
    select col1,col2 from your_table
    union all 
    select col1,col2 from your_table
    union all 
    select col1,col2 from your_table
    continued...
```

**Option 2 : Use dummy table with 10 records and do cross join**

Create a dummy table with 10 rows

```
insert into your_table (col1,col2)
select col1,col2 from your_table, dummy_table
```

Comment: `SELECT *` won't work with the primary keys, you'll get duplicate key errors.

Comment: You need to select all the columns except the `id` column.

Comment: You're overthinking this.

Answer (score 0):

If you have ~50K rows, then copying them 99 times will give you ~5M rows.
To do so, you can create a procedure and use a loop to copy them 99 times.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE populate()
BEGIN
  DECLARE counter INT DEFAULT 1;

  WHILE counter < 100 DO
    insert into mytable(colA, colB) select colA, colB from mytable;
    SET counter = counter + 1;
  END WHILE;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Then you can call the procedure using

```
call populate();
```

Comment: Hey, I have to say that it isn't 99 times but around 6 ! You see, since you are coping the same table over and over, the amount of lines is exponentially growing.